# INSERT HIVE SQL in loop in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

We are trying to run an INSERT SQL for HIVE with data coming out of a dataframe in Spark. The session used has  etc everything.

Have 2 issues:

Question) Even though we create session inside forEach loop, the INSERT is still failing when tried with both

1) Dataframes

2) Straight Spark SQL

Below is the code (Spark SQL Approach):

```
import java.time.Instant

import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, types}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{current_timestamp, first, isnull, lit, max}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType, TimestampType}

import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

class Controller extends DatabaseServices
  with Loggers {
  val session = createSparkSession(ConfigFactory.load().getString("local.common.spark.app.name"))
  val producer = session.sparkContext.broadcast(KafkaWrapper())

  def doIt(TranIDs: DataFrame): Unit = {
    import session.sqlContext.implicits._

    val TranID = TranIDs
      .withColumnRenamed("TranID", "REFERENCE_TranID")
      .select($"REFERENCE_TranID")
      .union(session.table(BANK_ROLLBACK_TXN_PRODUCER_LOG_VIEW)
        .withColumnRenamed("TranID", "REFERENCE_TranID")
        .select($"REFERENCE_TranID"))
      .where($"REFERENCE_TranID".isNotNull)

    if (TranID.count() == 0) {
      throw new Exception("No rows.")
    }

    val core = session
      .table(BANK_TRANS_MASTER_CORE)
      .withColumnRenamed("TranID", "MASTER_REFERENCE_TranID")
      .withColumnRenamed("CLIENTID", "REF_CLIENT_ID")
      .withColumnRenamed("SUBCLIENTID", "REF_SUBCLIENT_ID")
      .select($"MASTER_REFERENCE_TranID",
        $"TranIDDATE")
      .join(TranID, TranID.col("REFERENCE_TranID") === $"MASTER_REFERENCE_TranID")

    val ref = session
      .table(BANK_RBI_REF_CLIENT)
      .select($"CLIENTID", $"SUBCLIENTID", $"FLAGTRE")
      .join(core, $"CLIENTID" === core.col("REF_CLIENT_ID")
        && $"SUBCLIENTID" === core.col("REF_SUBCLIENT_ID")


    val details = session
      .table(BANK_TRANS_MASTER_DETAILS)
      .select($"TranID",
        $"REALFRAUD",
        $"REALFRAUDDATEBAE",
        $"REALFRAUDYYYYMMDD"
      )
      .join(ref, ref.col("MASTER_REFERENCE_TranID") === $"TranID"
        && $"REALFRAUD" === lit("Y"))
      .where($"TranID".isNotNull
        && $"TranIDDATE".isNotNull)
      .groupBy($"TranID")
      .agg(first($"TranID").as("TranID"),
        first(core("TranIDDATE")).cast("String").as("TranIDDATE"),
        max($"REALFRAUDDATEBAE").as("REALFRAUDDATEBAE"),
        max($"REALFRAUDYYYYMMDD").as("REALFRAUDYYYYMMDD"),
        first($"REALFRAUD").as("REALFRAUD"),
        first($"ABA").as("ABA"))

    details.foreach(row => {


      import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
      val transaction = TxUpdate.newBuilder().setTranID(row.getAs("TranID").toString)
        .setTranIDDATE(row.getAs("TranIDDATE").toString)
        .setAttributes(ListBuffer(
          Attribute.newBuilder.setKey("REALFRAUD").setValue(if (row.getAs("REALFRAUD") != null) row.getAs("REALFRAUD").toString else null).build(),
          Attribute.newBuilder.setKey("REALFRAUDDATEBAE").setValue(if (row.getAs("REALFRAUDDATEBAE") != null) if (row.getAs("REALFRAUDDATEBAE") != null) row.getAs("REALFRAUDDATEBAE").toString else null else null).build(),
          Attribute.newBuilder.setKey("REALFRAUDYYYYMMDD").setValue(if (row.getAs("REALFRAUDYYYYMMDD") != null) row.getAs("REALFRAUDYYYYMMDD").toString else null).build(),
          Attribute.newBuilder.setKey("ABA").setValue(if (row.getAs("ABA") != null) row.getAs("ABA").toString else null).build(),
        .build()

      if (producer.value.sendSync(ConfigFactory.load().getString("local.common.kafka.rollbackKafkaTopicName"),
        transaction.getTranID.toString,
        transaction)) {
        session.sqlContext.sql("insert into " + BANK_ROLLBACK_TXN_PRODUCER_LOG + "(TranID, when_loaded, status) values('" + transaction.getTranID.toString + "', 'current_timestamp()', 'S')")
      } else {
        session.sqlContext.sql("insert into " + BANK_ROLLBACK_TXN_PRODUCER_LOG + "(TranID, when_loaded, status) values('" + transaction.getTranID.toString + "', 'current_timestamp()', 'F')")
      }

    })

  }
}
```

Comment: This is a singleton insert to Hive. Bad approach.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, we had used df.write.insertInto with Append option also which gave errors. Finally made that to work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not clear here.

At a high level you can use the approach of enabling hivecontext within Spark and then directly do persist into Hive table using append option. This will be much faster than doing Insert operation. The flow will be something like this:

step 0- all this has to happen in a single spark session. You don't need to create multiple sessions for each insert. In a way this is meaningless to do. 
a. Create a data frame having the columns of the underlying table of Hive. 
b. During spark processing data frame gets its data to be persisted eventually in Hive. 
c. Initiate Dataframe saveastable with append option

[Insert Into Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219210/how-to-insert-spark-dataframe-to-hive-internal-table)

Hope this helps to understand how you need to approach this problem.

Comment: How can you give an answer if the issue is not clear?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help.

Answer (score 1):

We had used df.write.insertInto with Append option which gave errors. Finally made that to work.